# crashing error in cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource

Tags: opengl, cuda

I use the following code to clean up CUDA's use of a pair of pbos in preparation to recreate them at a different size:

```
glFinish();
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(m_cuda_pbo_resource));
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(m_cuda_pbo_depth_resource));
glDeleteBuffersARB(1, &m_pbo);
glDeleteBuffersARB(1, &m_pbo_depth);
```

During a resize operation of my window, this code is called in a draw operation while the window is redrawn at a new size.  Sometimes, the call to unregister m_cuda_pbo_resource fails and the program terminates.  This seems to have a higher chance of happening when the window is continuously being resized by the user as fast as possible. Because it doesn't happen all the time, it may be some sort of race condition, but I have run out of ideas of ways to try to debug it.

Comment: I have this exact same problem.

Comment: You have a problem with the same symptoms. I would be extremely surprised if, 12 years later, you have the same problem. I would be extremely surprised if the software stacks you are using had more than a few lines of common code over 12 years of enormous evolution.

Comment: Firefox has also undergone enormous evolution, yet there are bugs that have persisted for over a decade because no one can be bothered to fix them. Call me old and cynical but I can see no particular reason why the same wouldn't be true here.

Comment: A question on SO that only has non-upvoted answers may have some deficiencies in the question itself.  This question is 12 years old, but currently, in my view, such a question would be expected to include a [mcve]  (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), item #1).  Lack of a [mcve] for questions where it might reasonably be useful/helpful/appropriate makes it significantly harder to answer. I feel like I have written enough answers here so that I have some basis to make such a statement, but it hardly seems controversial in any event. Good luck getting a good answer without one!

Comment: You have a good point, but as I didn't ask the original question, how do I add a minimal example? Its hardly an 'Answer'?

Comment: Ask a new question.  There is no reason you can't bounty your own question instead of a 12-year old one.

Comment: Are you also running on CUDA 4.0, or have you upgraded to CUDA 12.1?

Comment: I'm actually running CUDA 11.5 as our shop is stuck on that until we're all ready to upgrade to 12.1

Answer (score 1):

You could be freeing the buffers while a kernel is running.  Try sticking a

```
   cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

Right before that block of code.

Comment: I did try cudaDeviceSynchronize(), which I believe is the preferred way to do it in CUDA 4.0.  No change though.

Comment: Ok, it's been a while since I've done GPGPU stuff.  Well, good luck and hope it isn't a driver bug!

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you are not trying to delete the buffer twice ?

How does it fails ? Error code ? Does your application have multiple threads ?

Does your application handle the case of resizing the PBO when the user resize the window ?

```
def on_resize( w, h):
    - lock_redraw
    - clean the PBO
    - reallocate the PBO of the new size
    - unlock redraw
```

Comment: I get an "Unknown error".  My code for the `on_resize` equivalent actually sets a flag and the PBO deletion and reallocation is done at the beginning of the draw call if the resize flag is set. I should not be calling CUDA from multiple threads.

Comment: did you unregistered them before deallocating ? can you post the relevant parts of your code ?

Comment: I call `cudaGraphicsUnmapResources()` after my kernel call, if that's what you're asking.  The crash is from `cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource()`.